# Android selector item precedence

Tags: android

My question is wether in Android you can have a selector item have precedence over another. I'm having the problem that the last item is being selected over the second item. In my code I use a listView and in both onItemClick and LongItemClick I have coded view.setHovered(true); which works only when the view is not activated. If it's activated @color/black is used instead of @color/white. Thanks in advance!

```
<item android:state_activated="false" android:state_hovered="false" android:color="@color/gray_light"/>
<item android:state_hovered="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:state_hovered="false" android:color="@color/black"/>
```

Edit1: Maybe this is the problem: Does it matter in which order v.setActivated / v.setHovered is called?
Edit2: I've put all v.setHovered(true) calls after v.setActivated(true) calls but it still chooses @color/black.

Comment: I found the answer to why the above wasn't working. It was a coding problem. I used setHovered and setActivated(true) on the container the TextView was in. Apparently state_activated then is also toggled to true for the TextView but stateHovered isn't. So I also used setHovered(true) on the TextView. Marking bwt's answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order. As stated by the [API guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom and the first item that  matches the current state is used—the selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

Comment: Edit: That doesn't explain why the last item is chosen over the second one. It explains why @color/white should be chosen instead of @color/black which is what I want :p

Comment: Good point. I just tried and it works when done in `getView()` but not in `onItemClick()`. By the way it's probably not a good idea to fiddle with a system managed state. The result may depend on the OS version and break at any time.